# How to use the plot function in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to plot 2 vectors again each other. The Julia documentation says I could just ex. write.

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); # These are the plotting data
plot(x, y)
```

But I get the following error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching NamedTuple(::Base.Generator{Base.Iterators.Filter{Plots.var"#131#134"{Dict{Symbol,Any}},NTuple{6,Symbol}},Plots.var"#130#133"{Dict{Symbol,Any}}})
Closest candidates are:
  NamedTuple() at boot.jl:545
  NamedTuple(!Matched::Union{Tables.AbstractColumns, Tables.AbstractRow})
```

What is the problem? I have used the example from the documentation and have not changed anything.

Comment: That code should work. It does for me. Try restarting your Julia session, checking if `println(x)` and `println(y)` display what you expect, and updating your Plots package.